# Driving a 5-Phase / 5-Wire Stepper Motor

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I have a penta-drive 5-phase motor with 5 wires that I'm looking to drive with a microcontroller and driver board.   I have a driver with 6 H-bridges that I was hoping to use.  If this was a 10-wire stepper where each coil is separate, its easy to connect and drive with 5 individual H-bridges.

How can I wire and drive this for the 5-wire setup properly?

Comment: yes but It depends what you specify...on max performance (CC) vs max simplicity (CV) and control by half step, full, PWM for max torque; speed; smoothness; efficiency  ( pick any 2 )  what is motor DCR and V rating?

Answer (score 3):

You connect each phase to a separate h-bridge output. Since there is no common wire, you will have to energize at least two coils. This page shows the specific details:
http://www.orientalmotor.com/technology/articles/2phase-v-5phase.html

[image]